# Как правильно сказать: вам не удалось подключиться или у вас не удалось подключиться?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать: вам не удалось подключиться или у вас не удалось подключиться?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно так:
*Вам не удалось подключиться.

У вас не **получилось** подключиться.*

"Удалось" (*кому?*) и "получилось" (*у кого?*) — это синонимы, но у них разное управление.